# Parse timestamp having hour beyond 23 in python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timestamp

I am learning python and came across an issue where I am trying to read timestamp from CSV file in below format,

> `43:32.0`

here 43 is at hours position and convert it to DateTime format in Pandas.

I tried code,

> `df['time'] = df['time'].astype(str).str[:-2]`
>
> `df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], errors='coerce')`

But, this is converting all values to **NaT**

I need the output to be in format - `mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss`

Comment: What is your expected out from this string?

Comment: what happens when you leave in the `.0`?

Comment: check the [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) documentation, especially the `format` parameter. To look what format you need, check the [`strptime` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)

Comment: Thank you all for responding to this thread. @Scott Boston, I want a date and time format output.

Comment: @MattR I am removing .0 so that string can be in timestamp format and 43 is at hours position and not minutes.

Comment: @Maarten Fabre, I tried to_datetime and strptime, a format is giving an error because in format %H does not recognize 43 as an hour.

Comment: When I'm transforming this format into excel it gives me,  1/0/00 12:35 AM as DateTime for 35:52.0

Comment: @Agrawal, did my solution work/not work? If not could you edit your question to include the desired data outcome?

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume that this is a Date for 11-29-17 (today's date)?

I believe you need to add an extra `0:` in the beginning of the string. Basic Example:

```
import pandas as pd
# creating a dataframe of your string
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A':['43:32.0']})
# adding '0:' to the front
df1['A'] = '0:' + df1['A'].astype(str)
# making new column to show the output
df1['B'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['A'], errors='coerce')
#output


           A                   B
0  0:43:32.0 2017-11-29 00:43:32
```

Comment: this is not working, as I said 43 is at hours position to_datetime is not recognizing this time and `errors='coerce'` is converting it to **NaT**.

Comment: @Agrawal, I may be asking a dumb question here, but why would 43 be in the hours position? there is no 43rd hour? If 43 goes into the hour position it will return `NaT`. If you run my example code, as shown it the ouput, it returns the 43 in the minutes position. If you add anything above 23 in the hours part (`23: + df1['A']`) you will get an error

Comment: That is the real cause of my issue. I am getting this format in excel file and when I format it to DateTime in excel file, it gives me 1/0/00 12:35 AM or 35:52.0